# How to add multi-key querystring to custom content type's custom form url?

Tags: content-type, xml, query-string

I have a custom content type, inheriting from the WorkflowTask content type.  I've configured the content type to point to a custom form, but the URLs are not working properly.

```
<ContentType
    ID="0x01080100E6578EE7F3CD4BCA8C6EA42C8FF3F24B"
    Name="Custom Task Content Type"
    Group="Custom Content Types"
    Description=""
    Inherits="TRUE"
    Version="0"
    Overwrite="TRUE"
>
    <FieldRefs>
        <FieldRef ID="{5E9EDA01-AFAF-4c6d-A3C4-A44C8418E519}" Name="_ApprovalNotes"/>
        <FieldRef ID="{886F1812-47CE-4cd7-AF93-C57EF5EBD171}" Name="_ApprovalStatus"/>
        <FieldRef ID="{CFB3DE92-106B-4c3e-84D2-9FBC3A3C5921}" Name="_Delegate"/>
        <FieldRef ID="{B923E7D6-7C56-447b-95A9-5CFB7854F7B7}" Name="_taskType"/>
    </FieldRefs>
    <XmlDocuments>
        <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms/url">
            <FormUrls>
                <New>_Layouts/project/custom Form.aspx?PageMode=New&amp;WFTask=1</New>
                <Edit>_Layouts/project/custom Form.aspx?PageMode=Edit&amp;WFTask=1</Edit>
                <Display>_Layouts/project/custom Form.aspx?PageMode=Display&amp;WFTask=1</Display>
            </FormUrls>
        </XmlDocument>
    </XmlDocuments>
</ContentType>
```

When adding this content type to the built-in Tasks list, the custom form URLs are not carried over.  So in the FeatureActivated event receiver, I have this code:

```
SPContentType ct = taskList.ParentWeb.AvailableContentTypes[contentTypeName];
if (ct != null)
{
    taskList.ContentTypes.Add(ct);
    taskList.Update();

    SPContentType ct2 = taskList.ContentTypes[contentTypeName];
    ct2.NewFormUrl = "_Layouts/project/custom Form.aspx?PageMode=New&WFTask=1";
    ct2.EditFormUrl = "_Layouts/project/custom Form.aspx?PageMode=Edit&WFTask=1";
    ct2.DisplayFormUrl = "_Layouts/project/custom Form.aspx?PageMode=Display&WFTask=1";
    ct2.Update();
}
```

Unfortunately, when I open the workflow task form, the received query string contains the key `amp;WFTask` rather than `WFTask`.  Why is the ampersand XML encoded and then directly used in the querystring rather than being decoded back to a proper ampersand?  How do I fix this?

Comment: As a work-around, I'm checking the querystring for the "amp;WFTask" key if "WFTask" is not found - this works, but in my development I've seen cases where the encoding resulted in "amp;amp;amp;WFTask" - as though it had been encoded three times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **%26** instead of **&**. It helped me. Like here:

```
<Edit>_Layouts/project/custom Form.aspx?PageMode=Edit%26WFTask=1</Edit>
```

Comment: Odd that that may work, I would assume the %26 would cause the `PageMode` parameter to equal `Edit%26WFTask=1` rather than giving me two parameters.  I may try this in the future, but right now the work-around functions and I'm under a time crunch to finish.

Comment: When I finally got time to test this (need to resolve became necessary when one of our environments double-encoded the ampersand `$amp;amp;WFTask=1`) the `%26` encoding resolved the problem.